# Best way to load Long Json file in angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am creating a Card game and loading all cards from json file, as i found it easier. I am loading json in normal way in angular as follow

> Script

```
app.controller('CardsController', function($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get("Card.json").success(function(response){
        $scope.Cards = response;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error loading json');
    });

    $scope.random = function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }
});
```

and i am iterating this json result in a div as follow

> html

```
<div id="leftSideHolder">
    <div ng-repeat="card in Cards | orderBy:random | limitTo:20">
        <div style="position:absolute;">
            <img src='images\{{card.image}}.{{card.imagetype1}}' width="154px" height="232px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But i am getting a error from Angular. [Error Link from Angular](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A138%2C%22oldVal%22%3A118%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%228_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%225_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22king_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%225_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%2210_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_spades2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22king_of_clubs2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%224_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22king_of_spades2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%227_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%226_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A156%2C%22oldVal%22%3A138%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%2210_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%229_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%229_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%224_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_clubs2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_hearts2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%227_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22king_of_hearts2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_hearts2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%229_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A176%2C%22oldVal%22%3A156%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%228_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%2210_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%2210_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%225_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%226_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_clubs2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A196%2C%22oldVal%22%3A176%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_clubs2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22king_of_spades2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%226_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%222_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%226_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%224_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%229_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%228_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22ace_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_hearts2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%225_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A215%2C%22oldVal%22%3A196%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%224_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_hearts2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%227_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%228_of_hearts%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%222_of_diamonds%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%223_of_clubs%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%222_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%2210_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%229_of_spades%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22jack_of_diamonds2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22queen_of_spades2%22%7D%2C%7B%22msg%22%3A%22fn%3A%20function%20(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%7Be%3Da(c%2Cd%2Ce%2Cf)%3Breturn%20b(e%2Cc%2Cd)%7D%22%2C%22newVal%22%3A%22png%22%7D%5D%5D). No idea what is this error :( i think its array initializing issue.

I tried that solution as below

```
var cardList = null;
$http.get("data/Cards.json").success(function(response){
        cardList = response;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error loading json');
    });

    $scope.Cards = function() {
       return cardList;
    }
```

and in html i used **Cards()** as follow

```
<div ng-repeat="card in Cards() | orderBy:random | limitTo:20">
    <div style="position:absolute;">
        <img src='images\{{card.image}}.{{card.imagetype1}}' width="154px" height="232px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

But still same issue. I tried to remove random also in ng-repeat, and this error goes. But i need to randomize the array also.

My code is in below link as well.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cQMXfVJFMhr3t1OG5G97?p=preview

Comment: are you sure about `images\ `  ? I guess it should be `images/`

Comment: Yes, You are also correct. its loading some of the images as well at my end but not all, due to the error message.

Comment: but the `\ ` may escape the angular tag `{`

Comment: Yes i changed this. But still same error. you can check http://plnkr.co/edit/cQMXfVJFMhr3t1OG5G97?p=preview for error message.

Comment: use `ng-src` to avoid making bad requests to server using uncompiled `src` values. Wep url paths don't use backslash they use `/`